# Number of ways to put one or more of $5$ books in $5$ bags

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> In how many ways can we put one or more of 5 books in to 5 bags?
>
> Additional info: books are labeled. Bags too. One or more bags can remain empty.

*Things I have done so far*:

There are $5$ situations :

Ways to put one book, ways to put two books $,\cdots,$ ways to put 5 books.

Situation #1 is easily countable. We have $5$ ways to choose a book, and $5$ ways to choose a bag. so number of ways is equal to $5\times5=25$

However from situations #2 to #5, I don't know exactly what to do. For example situation #2.

I choose $2$ books from $5$ books, there are ${5 \choose 2}$ ways to do this. but I can't find a good way for counting number of ways to put these books on bags.

Comment: Try to consistently use uppercase letters at the beginning of sentences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine there is a sixth bag, the donation bag. Line up the books in order, by age, or beauty, or ISBN number.

For each book, we can choose one of the $6$ bags to put it into, for a total of $6^5$ choices. Except we can't put them all in the donation bag, so there are $6^5-1$ ways.

**Remark:** In your approach, suppose we have chosen say $3$ books. We can choose the bags they go into in $5^3$ ways.

Comment: +1,your "Remark"s are always useful and nice.and $-\infty$ to me for my stupidy for handling problem in a such bad way.

Comment: You were doing it in a sensible way. If you use my remark and combine it with your approach, you may notice that your terms give (almost) the binomial expansion of $(1+5)^5$

Answer (score 1):

Using your method, you would get $\binom{5}{1}5+\binom{5}{2}5^2+\binom{5}{3}5^3+\binom{5}{4}5^4+\binom{5}{5}5^5=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{5}\binom{5}{k}5^k=\sum_{k=0}^{5}\binom{5}{k}5^k-1=(1+5)^5-1=6^5-1.$